# Is there a way to obtain a list of the links that Google has crawled?

Tags: google-search-console, url, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I was concerned that Google was not obtaining all the links on my site during their crawl, but after going into Google Tools it seems I have a few hundred URL's indexed every week (approximately), which I am relieved about.

However, I'd really like to see what links have been indexed to review and check for problem areas. Is there any method of obtaining a list of these indexed URL's?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the search operator to to search in Google for only your site, this should achieve what you want:

> Site:www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to set up a `sitemap.xml` file if you really want to cross-check and make sure that every single link on your site is indexed. This can be checked via webmaster tools too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Google Search with below convention (without `http://`):

```
site:yoursitename.com
```